# How to declare a module to export any no matter what exactly it exports?

Tags: typescript

My UI package does not have type definition files. When I use it in my TypeScript project

```
import { Cell } from 'zarm';
```

TSC will throw an error:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'zarm'.

I created a `global.d.ts` file and try to declare the `zarm` module to export anything.

```
declare module 'zarm' {
  const x: any;
  export = x;
}
```

TSC throws:

> Module '"zarm"' has no exported member 'Cell'.

There are many components in `zarm` module, I just want to declare the `zarm` module to export `any`. Don't care what exactly it exports.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Shorthand ambient modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#shorthand-ambient-modules).

> If you don’t want to take the time to write out declarations before using a new module, you can use a shorthand declaration to get started quickly.

Just declare the module for the existed JavaScript package `zarm` like below in `global.d.ts` type definition file:

```
declare module 'zarm';
```

It will let you import the `zarm` module with `any` type. So that I can import any component from the module without using the `//@ts-ignore` comment to skip TSC type check.

```
import { Button, Popup } from 'zarm';
```